# Software project workflow template for the lonely programmer?

Tags: software-development, documentation

My problem is simple: I am the only software developer in an organization trying to start organizing projects for me. Management directors don't care and ignore EVERYTHING about corporate governance or project management. I only present some documentation to cover my back but I know they don't read anything I've sent.

I want to have a template for my project, a simple workflow to follow for small software projects.

I've read some books which talks about: "Calculating the communication channels", "Calculating the critical paths", "Cost estimating", "Quality policies", etc. and I have nothing against these good practices, but I'm alone and I have to minimize my time investment, specially when I have people asking for immediate results.

Is there some simple project management steps or workflow (must-have) for lonely developers? (I don't need a software, just a generic template).

For example: [Computer Repair with Diagnostic Flowcharts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0972380175) is a book which contains workflows for typical simple problems with computers. Is there something like that for PM and specifically for my scenario?

Comment: Hi Miguel, welcome to PMSE. I'd say that you could improve a little bit about what is the problem you're trying to solve, as `PM steps or workflows` are means to an objective instead of the objective itself. So, instead of asking for ways to reach something, clarify what are you trying to accomplish with such methodologies you're looking for.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not saying that I 100% understand what you need, but maybe your are looking for something similar to [Personal Kanban](http://www.personalkanban.com/pk/personal-kanban-101/). It

- provides/**visualizes** you and your manager your actual status
- can help you see your activities as a whole
- helps you find your **limitations** (WIP), in other words how much tasks you can do in parallel
- provides your manager the possibility for **prioritization**

You can have four different phases like:

- *Queued*: the place for your new tasks
- *Implementation*: the place for your ongoing tasks
- *Validation*: where you check whether your solution is the one your were asked to deliver
- *Done*: what you accomplished/finished/delivered

Comment: I agree. A Kanban board is what you need to organise your work.

Comment: http://agilezen.com can be used as an online board

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like a physical whiteboard(laid out as a grid) in your lonely castle, public enough for others to view in case they ask for progress .

The entities that it could cover is -

1. Your development/test work broken down into atomic tasks as rows of the grid .
2. The workflow stage as the columns of the grid -In queue, started/thinking , coding , Almost done/testing , Done , Blocked
3. A separate area to highlight blocked tasks/issues
4. Something like this  to indicate quality status of your tasks/software release as a whole to make ship/no ship decisions - http://www.satisfice.com/presentations/dashboard.pdf  (slide 8)

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Trello](http://trello.com)? It is simple web application that can help you organize your projects.

There are 3 functions in this application:

1. Board: you can create *Board* for each project
2. List: every *Board* have some list. If you create a new *Board*, it will automatically create 3 *Lists* such as To Do, Doing, and Done. You can add a new list later or modify the existing ones.
3. Card: the discussions go here. You can also add Checklist, Attachment, Due Date, and so on...